# jQuery: Deleting an object with click causing undesired loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, click

I have a a bit of code which selects these simple spans on my site and applies a "click" event handler to them.  Specifically, it calls the "deletePerson" function.  Here's the class selection code:

```
jQuery('.delete-person').click(function() {
      var type = jQuery(this).data('type');
      var number = jQuery(this).data('number');
      deletePerson(type, number);
});
```

The deletePerson function is a little complex, but essentially what it does is replaces the deleted person's information with the next person's in the list.  This shift also happens the entire list of people "above" the deleted party, to maintain sequential ordering.  There is also a confirmation message before the delete occurs.

The problem, I believe, is that **when I click the delete-person span on Person1, it confirms deleting Person1, then continues with prompts for a number of times equal to people in the list**.

For example: if there are 3 people and you say "no" to deleting Person1 (1st prompt) it will ask you to delete Person1 again (2nd prompt).  If you say "yes" to the second prompt, the delete will occur, as will the shift, and it will prompt you (3rd prompt) to delete Person2 (since they are now in the #1 spot).

I feel like there's a simple solution here, but I can't see it.  My apologies if this has been asked already, I've been searching (Google and Stackoverflow) for the past half-hour without luck.

**EDIT**

Here is the deletePerson function... a little complicated and messy, as I warned (I'm working on a simple jsFiddle to demo my problem):

[UGLY CODE REMOVED]

**EDIT 2**

Here is the fiddle I quickly made to demo that, in fact, I am an idiot and the functionality I want is possible, I'm just screwing up elsewhere: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtEuj/

**EDIT 3**

epascarello was correct, I was attaching the click listener multiple times (jQuery newbie mistake!).  Simply adding `jQuery('.delete-person').off()` before my original code sample fixed it wonderfully.

**Thank you epascarello!**

Comment: Well, there is nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted, so you'd have to provide more information (code).

Comment: Show the prompt code... Sounds like the problem is there, not in the code you posted.

Comment: I added that whole function, but warning it is messy at present!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now after thinking about it. I think it has NOTHING to do with the code you posted.

You are attaching the onclick event multiple times for the same function call.

AKA

```
for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    jQuery('.delete-person').click(function() {   ... });
}
```

Do not attach the event multiple times.

Use event bubbling to your advantage and do not worry about adding events for newly created elements

```
jQuery(document).on("click", '.delete-person", function() {   ... });
```

It is better to replace document with an element that has the elements.

If you do not want to rely on the bubbling, there is `off()`, but it will delete all the events attached.

Comment: I suspect you're right.  I'm terribly new to jQuery and didn't realize you COULD attach multiple click listeners.  (I suppose I figured it would only attach one.)

Is there a way to clear the existing ones?  Seeing as the members are dynamically populated it would be a pain to add a click listener to only the new ones.

Comment: Yes it is completly valid to have multiple click events on an element that do different things.